# Firebug Script debugger is not worked in Firefox lowest version releases

Tags: firefox, firefox-developer-tools

Actually i have used the Firefox below release of 40. Firebug is not working properly cant able to debug the script. Is it possible to update the new version every time.

Answer (score 1):

Firefox has a debugger now! Go to Tools > Web Developer > Debugger.

Here is the documentation and an instructional video:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger